# How to pulse a signal at 100ms to 500ms?

Tags: pulsein

Based on [this PDF](http://img.banggood.com/file/products/20150922040956Joyhonest%202210M%20Camera%20datasheet%20from%20Wind.pdf) I need to pulse between 100ms and 500ms to record a video (the description is apparently wrong according to [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyYe1y7kBek&ab_channel=Vortecks)). How would I generate such a pulse? The small module has 3 wires I can use, which are positive, ground, and a yellow wire. I assume I need to pulse the yellow wire.

I don't want to hook anything up wrong, but my guess would be using [`pulseIn()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PulseIn). However, I am not sure at all. Any help appreciated.

Comment: According to the pdf you need > 500ms for video...  100 - 500 is photo.

Comment: @Majenko That is wrong according to some guy, but that doesn't really matter anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so pulsing is apparently easy enough. If I just do:

```
digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(13, LOW);
delay(1000);
```

It will start recording, then turn off about a second later, start again about a second later, and then repeat. I somehow managed to get a 5 second recording as well. I'm not really sure how this is supposed to work. I need to test some more.

EDIT: Turns out the schematics were right. If I do something as simple as:

```
digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(13, LOW);
delay(1000);
```

It will turn on the video recording and turn off whenever it gets HIGH again.